# Can I access the Twitter notification filters from the api?

Tags: twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I am trying to access the settings for a Twitter user using the api, specifically the notification filters.

For example I would like to build a code that turns on these filters or turns them off, for example the "only see notifications from those you follow/follow you"

I don't see any documentation on this or through Tweepy either. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no API feature for this.